# Maven: How to set a dependency's classpath?

Tags: java, maven, h2

I'm running a Spring MVC 2.5.6 project, which uses h2 database for test. My database in production is MySQL(I know I should use MySQL for test, too). A MySQL-specific function `timediff` is not implemented in h2. So I want to add a user-specific function to h2 using [this doc](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions) . I wonder how I can add a `.class` file compiled from the function I wrote to h2's classpath? Sinch h2 is in pom like this:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.197</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```